# Magento 2 - What will be the future of Magento Community (Open Source) Edition after acquisition by Adobe

Tags: magento2, magento-community

Recently, I got a news that Magento has been acquired by Adobe for $1.68 billion.

I have also read [here](https://thenextweb.com/insider/2018/05/22/adobe-acquires-ecommerce-cms-magento-for-1-68-billion/), that Adobe likely has plans to change things around the way Magento is made available to developers and businesses.

What will happen after the deal completes in the third quarter of 2018?

Will Magento Community (Open Source) Edition still available for free?

As we all know that none of the products from Adobe are Open Source, will Magento become restricted to the developers like Shopify?

Will there be only Cloud Edition of Magento in the future?

There are many such comments on the web to support my concern:

- https://www.linkedin.com/feed/update/urn:li:activity:6404580085004849152

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/226921/adobe-buys-magento-community-edition-future

Comment: @RaulSanchez, Not a duplicate, since there are many valid reasons provided in my post.

Comment: @MohitKumarArora Though this type of question not fit at here you can ask on community.magento.com

Comment: @MurtuzaZabuawala, thanks for sharing your suggestions. I have posted the question on community.magento.com also.

Answer (score 2):

MagentoCE will remain open source  check this tweet from adobe

https://twitter.com/mjasay/status/998930665805496321

Answer (score 1):

You guys can also check out reddit post related to this issue here;
https://www.reddit.com/r/Magento/comments/a16vnd/adobe_shutting_down_magento_2_open_source/